# Converting html site to static wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am converting a single page html site into a static wordpress site.
The original html homepage(the only page) mainly uses jquery to drop down a small text area when clicked on an option in the menu far.
Attaching the index.php of my converted theme.

```
<div class="content" id="content1">
<a href="" onclick="deanimate('content1')"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/close.png" style="position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px; width:15px;"/></a>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/face.png" style="padding-left:15px; padding-top:20px; width:454px;" />
</div>


<div class="content" id="content2">
<a href="" onclick="deanimate()"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/close.png" style="position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px; width:15px;"/></a>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/face2.png" style="padding-right:15px; padding-top:30px; width:453px; height:200px;" />
</div>
```

and so on ..
I want to add the content in such a way that I should be able to modify it in wordpress app without editing the theme file ? Is it possible ? New to wordpress. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is possible but your Question is really too vague. Consult the [**Codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and maybe some tutorials at [**WPTuts**](http://wp.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/theme-development/).

Comment: Theirs a very simple and free program on http://www.wpsiteconvertor.com/ which you could use to convert your website to wordpress fast

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can edit content from wp-admin. In page management under admin you can create pages, then add loop in page.php or your template file it will display the content which you have written in admin.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title();?>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

With the above code you can display page management content on browser.